# sed: -e expression #1, char 62: unknown command: `\'

Tags: sed

I am trying to add

```
-
  paths:
    - /var/log/consumer.log
  document_type: consumer
  input_type: log
```

after `prospectors:` in my file. I am using command:

```
sed -i '/prospectors:/a\ \ \ \ \-
\ \ \ \ \ \ paths:\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \- \/var\/log\/consumer.log
\ \ \ \ \ \ document_type: consumer
\ \ \ \ \ \ input_type: log' new.txt
```

But the above command gives following error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 62: unknown command: `\'

How can I achieve the desired?

Answer (score 1):

In classic (POSIX) `sed`, each line of data appended needs to be on its own line after the `a` command, and all lines except the last need a backslash at the end to indicate that the data continues. GNU `sed` allows some information on the same line as the `a` command, but otherwise follows the rules.

There's an additional wrinkle: `sed` removes leading blanks from the data.  To get the leading blanks, you can use backslash-blank at the start.

Hence, you can end up with:

```
sed -i '/prospectors:/a \
        \    -\
        \      paths:\
        \        - /var/log/consumer.log\
        \      document_type: consumer\
        \      input_type: log' new.txt
```

The leading blanks are ignored; the backslash is deleted; the following blanks are copied to the output.  Thus given an input containing just a line containing `prospectors:`, the output is:

```
prospectors:
    -
      paths:
        - /var/log/consumer.log
      document_type: consumer
      input_type: log
```

Obviously, you can adjust the spacing to suit yourself.

I note that BSD `sed` requires a suffix after the `-i` option; it can be `-i ''` to get an 'empty string' suffix.  To be portable between GNU and BSD `sed`, use `-i.bak` (no space; GNU `sed` doesn't like the space; BSD `sed` accepts the attached suffix, but you can't attach an empty suffix).  And the `-i` option is not mandated by POSIX, so it isn't available on all Unix-like systems.  If you're only using GNU `sed`, you don't have to worry about this trivia.